# What are the key features of the Canon Speedlite 320EX?

Tags: canon, flash, hotshoe-flash, features

I would like to find out the new key features of Canon Speedite 320EX and how to use them and to improve my flash photography.

I have stated down three key areas but please feel free to add more and explain how they can be used in real life situations:

1. LED Light Sensor
2. Wireless Slave unit
3. Flash release function

Comment: Hi Rick. This would really be better with one question about each feature you're interested in.

Answer (score 3):

### LED Light

The Canon Speedlite 320EX has an **LED light** feature that serves a few purposes. First and foremost I believe it is geared towards **video capture**, and provides a constant steam of light that is required of video fill light.

Secondary uses of the LED light include modeling light and the ability to provide illumination for AF while in live view mode.

In real life, you can use this for anything you would use a flashlight or set of LED lights for. It could illuminate your subjects, or it could illuminate your bag while on a nighttime photo walk.